# Scrapy request, shell Fetch() in spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to reach a specific page, let's call it `http://example.com/puppers`. This page cannot be reached when connecting directly using `scrapy shell` or the standard `scrapy.request` module (results in  `<405> HTTP`).

However, when I use `scrapy shell 'http://example.com/kittens'` first, and then use `fetch('http://example.com/puppers')` it works and I get a `<200> OK HTTP` code. I can now extract data using `scrapy shell`.

I tried implementing this in my script, by altering the `referer` (using url #1), the `user-agent` and a few others while connecting to the *puppers* (url #2) page. I still get a <405> code..

I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you share the URL or your code. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_urls = ['http://example.com/kittens']

def parse(self, response):

    yield scrapy.Request(

        url="http://example.com/puppers",
        callback=self.parse_puppers
    )

def parse_puppers(self, response):
    #process your puppers
    .....
```